# Why I Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an argument of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')?

Tags: swift, dictionary

I have an array that I want to convert to a dictionary and I declared a function to do so but I get this error each time I compile 
"Cannot subscript a value of type '[String : [String]]' with an argument of type 'String.SubSequence' (aka 'Substring')"

my code is

```
let animals = ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo", "Camel", "Cockatoo", "Dog", "Donkey", "Emu", "Giraffe", "Greater Rhea", "Hippopotamus", "Horse", "Koala", "Lion", "Llama", "Manatus", "Meerkat", "Panda", "Peacock", "Pig", "Platypus", "Polar Bear", "Rhinoceros", "Seagull", "Tasmania Devil", "Whale", "Whale Shark", "Wombat"]
   var animalsDict = [String: [String]]()
    var animalSectionTitles = [String]()

 func createAnimalDict() {
        for animal in animals {
            let secondLetterIndex = animal.index(animal.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let animalKey = animal[..<secondLetterIndex]
            if var animalValues = animalsDict[animalKey] {
                animalValues.append(animal)
                animalsDict[animalKey] = animalValues
            }else {
                animalsDict[animalKey] = [animal]
            }
        }
        animalSectionTitles = [String](animalsDict.keys)
        animalSectionTitles = animalSectionTitles.sorted(by: { $0 < $1 })
    }
```

I expect to get this dictionary after converting to fill a tableview with this dictionary which its key refer to section title and its values refer to the rows' titles

```
let animals: [String: [String]] = ["B" : ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo"],

"C" : ["Camel", "Cockatoo"],

"D" : ["Dog", "Donkey"],

"E" : ["Emu"],

"G" : ["Giraffe", "Greater Rhea"],

"H" : ["Hippopotamus", "Horse"],

"K" : ["Koala"],

"L" : ["Lion", "Llama"],

"M" : ["Manatus", "Meerkat"],

"P" : ["Panda", "Peacock", "Pig", "Platypus", "Polar Bear"],

"R" : ["Rhinoceros"],

"S" : ["Seagull"],

"T" : ["Tasmania Devil"],

"W" : ["Whale", "Whale Shark", "Wombat"]]
```

Comment: What output 'dictionary' do you expect from `animals' array?

Comment: @PGDev I edited the question to demonstrate how the output dictionary should be look like

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply use `Dictionary's` **`init(grouping:by:)`** `initializer` like so,

```
var animalsDict = Dictionary(grouping: animals) { String($0.first!) }

var animalSectionTitles = animalsDict.keys.sorted()
```

**Output:**

```
print(animalsDict) //["G": ["Giraffe", "Greater Rhea"], "P": ["Panda", "Peacock", "Pig", "Platypus", "Polar Bear"], "E": ["Emu"], "H": ["Hippopotamus", "Horse"], "K": ["Koala"], "L": ["Lion", "Llama"], "R": ["Rhinoceros"], "D": ["Dog", "Donkey"], "B": ["Bear", "Black Swan", "Buffalo"], "M": ["Manatus", "Meerkat"], "W": ["Whale", "Whale Shark", "Wombat"], "S": ["Seagull"], "T": ["Tasmania Devil"], "C": ["Camel", "Cockatoo"]]

print(animalSectionTitles) //["B", "C", "D", "E", "G", "H", "K", "L", "M", "P", "R", "S", "T", "W"]
```

Comment: Well, this is an amazing answer and made my code way too fewer , may you please explain what is the String($0.first!) ?

Comment: `String($0.first!)` is the key for the `Dictionary` based on which the elements are grouped.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is convert the `Substring`, namely `animalKey` to a `String` and your code works just as expected.

```
let animalKey = String(animal[..<secondLetterIndex])
```

Comment: Yes, your answer worked fine with me , may I explain this conversion a little bit because it is kinda vague to me and I can not get the point behind typing string before (animal[..<secondLetterIndex]) ?

Comment: @AhmedBahgat you simply need to pass the `Substring` to a `String` initialiser. `Substring` and `String` are different types and your `Dictionary` is of type `Dictionary<String,String>`, so you need `String`s as keys for your `Dictionary`. Hence you need to convert the `Substring` into a `String`, which you can do using `String`'s init that takes a `Substring`.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer since it answered the question as it was asked.